# devise_invitable : allowing non-devise models to set and send invitations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm configuring devise_invitable and I need to have a model that is not a devise model set and send invitations.

The readme has instructions for setting this by devise models(e.g. only devise Admin model), but not an external non-devise model(e.g. I have an specific Inviter user but it isn't a devise model).

I'm curious if anyone has done this or what advice you would offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works through setting this is the Application controller:

```
protected
  def authenticate_inviter!
  end
```

Not entirely sure of the security ramifications in depth, but it works for now.